# Vector dot product and scalar multiplication in Grapher.app

Tags: software, grapher

I'm trying to play around with vectors in Grapher.app, but I'm getting an error when I try to A: multiply two vectors (specified as a vertical matrix) together, and B: multiply a vector by a scalar value. Here's my dilemma in picture form: [image: vector math in grapher]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to multiply two column vectors don't you have to transpose one of them? I got the transpose operator by typing `^T`. (That's caret + T, not Ctrl+T)

I was able to multiply a vector by a scalar.

[image: vector operations]

In your screenshot, the subscripts aren't consistent. Maybe it's part of your problem or maybe it's just some math I don't understand. This is all on the edge of my math knowledge.

## Epilogue

For those who are interested, here is bjz's screenshot of his working version:

[image: working version]

Comment: Cheers mate, I [got it to work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sDP7B.png). And yes, my maths knowledge isn't great – I'm just using Grapher to sketch out my algorithms before I commit to code.